# Source maps not working on sentry when client side error occurs (webpack-plugin used with Next js 13)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13, sentry, source-maps

I followed the manual setup to send sourcemaps to sentry with @sentry/webpack-plugin and @sentry/nextjs since I use Next js framework on my project. The new release created on sentry includes artifactsfor source map including .map file and my original files.

When I make up a server error, it successfully show up on sentry with source map applied, but the errors from my client-side files shows errors with minified codes (although the release includes the client-side files as artifacts).

Wishing there is a solution for this...